# How to pass a table from frontend to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to pass a table as a parameter to a stored procedure. Is it possible to do it.
Please give some example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) - pass in a TABLE type as a parameter to a sproc.

I wrote up an article on the differences of the various approaches you could take, with a performance comparison here: [CSV vs XML vs Table Valued Parameter](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this

Convert you datable in xml by using datatable.Writexml

than pass this xml as string in stored procedure parmeter with the datatype Varchar(max)

Than use `OpenXml` to create datatable again form the xml string passed by you.

See the example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx